# Deadbolt 2 and Play 2.4.x: Null pointer exception on unaccessible pages

Tags: java, playframework, deadbolt, deadbolt-2

I'm trying to implement a simple autentication system in Play Framework 2.4.x using Deadbolt 2.

I've followed this [guide](https://leanpub.com/deadbolt-2/read) written by Chaloner and I've implemented my deadbolt handler as you can see here:

```
public class MyDeadboltHandler extends AbstractDeadboltHandler {

    public F.Promise<Optional<Result>> beforeAuthCheck(Http.Context context) {
        // returning null means that everything is OK.  Return a real result if you want a redirect to a login page or
        // somewhere else
        return F.Promise.promise(Optional::empty);
    }

    public F.Promise<Optional<Subject>> getSubject(Http.Context context) {
        // in a real application, the user name would probably be in the session following a login process
        User user = new User("MyUser", "my.email@info.com");
        return F.Promise.promise(() -> Optional.ofNullable(user));
    }

    public F.Promise<Optional<DynamicResourceHandler>> getDynamicResourceHandler(Http.Context context) {
        return F.Promise.promise(() -> Optional.of(new MyDynamicResourceHandler()));
    }

    @Override
    public F.Promise<Result> onAuthFailure(final Http.Context context, final String content) {
        // you can return any result from here - forbidden, etc
        return F.Promise.promise(() -> Controller.redirect(routes.Application.index()));
    }
}
```

My main controller is this:

```
public class Application extends Controller {

    public Result index() {
        return ok(index.render());
    }

    @SubjectPresent
    public Result denyAccess(){
        return ok(notAllowed.render());
    }

    public Result permitAccess(){
        return ok(allowed.render());
    }

    public Result errorPage(){
        return ok(errorPage.render());
    }
}
```

The problem appears when I try to access the page rendered by the action `denyAccess`. In this case I get a NullPointerException on page without a stack trace I can read, as you can see in the following image.

[image]

It seems that the method onAuthFailure is never invoked even when I try to access the controller denyAccess.

You can see the complete project [here](https://github.com/Ema-jar/PlayLogin) on my github page, it's very short and I think it can help you to understand the problem.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You should be able to see more information in the console running play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in your implementation of `HandlerCache`:

```
@Singleton
public class MyHandlerCache implements HandlerCache {

    private final Map<String, DeadboltHandler> handlers = new HashMap<>();

    public MyHandlerCache() {
        handlers.put("DEFAULT_KEY", new MyDeadboltHandler());
    }

    @Override
    public DeadboltHandler apply(final String key) {
        return handlers.get(key);
    }

    @Override
    public DeadboltHandler get() {
        return handlers.get("DEFAULT_KEY");
    }
}
```

By default, the default handler key name is defined by `be.objectify.deadbolt.java.ConfigKeys.DEFAULT_HANDLER_KEY` but in `MyHandlerCache` you use `"DEFAULT_KEY"`.  However, when this method is called:

```
public DeadboltHandler apply(final String key) {
    return handlers.get(key);
}
```

it will receive `be.objectify.deadbolt.java.ConfigKeys.DEFAULT_HANDLER_KEY` as a key and return null.

I'll make sure this is logged better and made clear in the documentation.  To fix your implementation, replace `"DEFAULT_KEY"` with `be.objectify.deadbolt.java.ConfigKeys.DEFAULT_HANDLER_KEY`:

```
@Singleton
public class MyHandlerCache implements HandlerCache {

    private final Map<String, DeadboltHandler> handlers = new HashMap<>();

    public MyHandlerCache() {
        handlers.put(ConfigKeys.DEFAULT_HANDLER_KEY, new MyDeadboltHandler());
    }

    @Override
    public DeadboltHandler apply(final String key) {
        return handlers.get(key);
    }

    @Override
    public DeadboltHandler get() {
        return handlers.get(ConfigKeys.DEFAULT_HANDLER_KEY);
    }
}
```

Comment: It solved the issue. Thank you steve and congratulation for your module, I like Deadbolt ;-)